# VirtualBox Internal Network's virtual switch

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bridge

I've encountered an issue in my envioronment using internal network. I've got two vms connected to the internal network. One of the vms has linux bridge running. This bridge has vms internal network interface connected and interface of linux namespace connected. Both second vm and namespace Have addresses from same subnet. When I send ping either from namespace to vm or vice versa, arp requests are being forwarded via internal network but replays dont. I see that vm or namespace are replaying on tcpdump but The replays are not forwarded via intnet . Can someone explain how internal network's vswitch works ? I attach the environment sketch. [image]

PS. This happens on Both linux nad Windows hosts. I've got firewall stopped on Both guest oses.

Thank you in advance,
Wojtek

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve ultimately.

Comment: I want to achieve connection between namespace and vm a. When pinging vma from namespace, arp request is forwarded to vm a, vm a sends replay but performing tcpdump on vm b enp0s8 or br0 interface I can't see any replay packet. This is why i suspect virtualbox internal network malfunction.

Comment: The vbox vswitch is a bridge, just like br0 in your Linux machine. It works exactly like an unmanaged layer 2 switch (e.g. your everyday dumb 8 port switch).

Comment: Okay so it should learn mac addresses (for example of namespace's arp request) But it is not possible i think to inspect this "virtual switch" fdb...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am now quite convinced that it might be Centos issue. I found a post where a user had similar issue. He wrote that after upgradinf kernel from 3.10 to 4.4 a linux bridge started forwarding arp responses. Anyone had similar issues ?